# Finding midnights from timestamp range

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

(Unix)Timestamp range is defined by two timestamps. I need find all midnights (00:00:00) in that range independently to summer/winter time.

```
//Timestamp range
$starttime = 1465997243; //Wed, 15 Jun 2016 15:27:23 CEST
$endtime = 1466321567; //Sun, 19 Jun 2016 07:32:47 CEST

//Expected output
1: 1466028000 //Thu, 16 Jun 2016 00:00:00 CEST
2: 1466114400 //Fri, 17 Jun 2016 00:00:00 CEST
3: 1466200800 //Sat, 18 Jun 2016 00:00:00 CEST
4: 1466287200 //Sun, 19 Jun 2016 00:00:00 CEST
```

Main problem is in different timezone and summer/winter time. Do you know any effective solution (no need for summer/winter time switching, timezone shifting)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like that

```
$starttime = 1465997243; //Wed, 15 Jun 2016 15:27:23 CEST
$endtime = 1466321567; //Sun, 19 Jun 2016 07:32:47 CEST
while(date('z',$starttime)<date('z',$endtime)){
    echo $starttime = strtotime(date('Y-m-d',$starttime).' +1 day midnight'),"<br>";
}
```

Comment: WOW what kind of black magic you use? It works nicely. I have no idea how to test with winter time, but i think it should works.